How do I set the data type to integer for a source-to-destination mapping in a data pipeline schema in JSON?
In fabric I'm trying to load lakehouse table from lakehouse file using data pipeline. Now I want to map data type while loading data from file to table using mapping variable (json object). Here I mentioned what I used
{
  "mappings": [
      {
          "source": {
              "name": "CountryOrder",
              "type": "string" 
          },
          "sink": {
              "name": "order",
              "type": "integer"
          }
      }
  ]
}

This is what I tried, it created column but can not convert data type string to integer.
Now I'm looking for valid json schema syntax to convert my target datatype
